# Почему при создании связи между сущностями появляется дополнительный параметр в хранимой процедуре

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый день!
Проект на C#, использую Entity Framework. Пытаюсь описать модель данных через Fluent API Entity FrameWork.

В конфигурации модели добавляю связь один ко многим:

```
HasRequired(t => t.MemberProcess).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.ProcessId);
```

Для добавления/удаления/обновления записей использую хранимые процедуры: MapToStoredProcedures().

До добавления связи все работает хорошо. Я добавляю нормально в таблицу записи. После появления связи в список параметров добавляется `@MemberProcess_ProcessId=NULL` . Что приводит к ошибке "Слишком много аргументов", что и понятно ведь у меня нет такого параметра в таблице.

При этом в этой же таблице добавляю связь к другой таблице :
 `HasRequired(t => t.TaskTypes).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.TaskTypeId);`
И всё работает хорошо, новых параметров не добавляется.

Не могу понять, почему так происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сутки мучился с этой проблемой. Но стоило мне только задать вопрос, спокойно и вдумчиво прочитать руководство по Fluent API, как пришло решение.
Заменил:

```
HasRequired(t => t.MemberProcess).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.ProcessId);
```

на

```
 HasRequired(t => t.MemberProcess).WithMany(t => t.Tasks).HasForeignKey(f => f.ProcessId);
```

И всё заработало. Спасибо всем!